# Let $G$ be a Lie group and $v\in X_L(G)$. Then $v$ is complete.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

There is a proposition in my textbook that states,

" Let $G$ be a Lie group and   $v\in X_L(G)$. Then $v$ is complete. "

I believe that $X_L(G)$ is the left-invariant vector field, so then I interpret the theorem as if $G$ is a Lie group then all left-invariant vector fields are complete. I know that for this to be true then the flow must exist for all ??$\in\mathbb{R}$, would this be for all $v \in \mathbb{R}$?

How would I prove the proposition?

My idea:
Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and $v \in \mathfrak g$. Write $X_L(G)$ as the left-invariant vector field on $\mathfrak g$ with $v \in X_L(G)$. Then
$$\phi_t(a) = a\gamma x(t) $$
is the flow of $X_L(G)$

Then for all $a\in G$ we have
$$\frac{d}{dt} |_{t=s} a\gamma x(t) = (dL_a)_{\gamma x(s)}(\frac{d}{dt}_{t=s} \gamma x(t))$$
$$= (dL_a)_{\gamma x(s)}(\frac{d}{dt}_{t=s} \gamma x(t+s))$$
$$=(dL_a)_{\gamma x(s)}(\frac{d}{dt}_{t=s} \gamma x(s) \gamma x (t))$$
$$=(dL_a)_{\gamma x(s)}(\frac{d}{dt}_{t=s}  L_{\gamma x(s)}(\gamma x (t)))$$
$$=(dL_a)_{\gamma x(s)}1(\frac{d}{dt}_{t=s} \gamma x (t))$$
$$=(dL_a)_{\gamma x(s)}(X)$$
$$=X_L(G)(a\gamma x(s))$$
which would show that the flow of $X_L(G)$ exists for all $t$?

Any help would be appreciated. I find this topic very difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes $X_L(G)$ denotes the lie algebra of the lie group , i.e , the set of left-invariant vector fields or equivalently $T_e G$. Now for a vector field to be complete we have to show that it's flow is defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, by definition. So take a left-invariant vector field $X$ and for example the identity $e$ in $G$. By results from ordinary differential equations there will exists an integral curve for $X$, $c_e(t)$ for $t\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ such that $c_h(0)=e$. Now the idea is to use the left-translations of a lie group which are diffeomorphism to extend this curve to the lie group that is take $t_0 \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and we have that $c_e(t_0)c_e(t)$ will define an integral curve for $X$ at $c_e(t_0)$, where we use here the fact that $X$ is left-invariant. Now this curve is extending our previous one, and so by uniquess of the Picard-Lindelof theorem we have this curve extends, i.e, we can always extend it's interval of definition. Doing this again and again for all the points you get the desired result.

Here I will actually compute the differential so that things are clear :

Let $g=c_e(t_0)$ then we have that $\frac{d}{dt}gc_e(t)=\frac{d}{dt}L_g(c_e(t))=\frac{d}{ds}|_{s=0}L_g(c_e(t+s))=d_{c_e(t)}L_g(X_{c_e(t)})=X_{gc_e(t)}$.

Comment: Could you explain where you say, "By results from ordinary differential equations there will exists an integral curve for $X$, $c_e(t)$ for $t\in(\epsilon,\epsilon)$ such that $c_h(0)=e$" why you are doing this or why you chose this?

(The differential makes sense, thank you.)
Then I know that the Picard-Lindelof theorem says that if X is locally Lipschitz continuous then the solution $u_x$ is unique. However, how would you actually prove this last section?

Comment: I am doing this becasue that's how you prove that the flow actually exists for an arbritary vector field , you take a curve and the vector field and put it in local coordinates and you get a system of ordinary differential equations in an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can solve them for some interval and then you have a curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and you compose with a chart to get a curve on your manifold. If you want I can add this process to my answer but I belive this is done in most differential geometry texts.